# Recursively scan all links in a website

Tags: c#, recursion, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I've built a scraper in C#, that scrapes all the pages from a link, and so other data, and tries to recreate the website. I want to make it scan recursively all the links, inside the links, inside the links, until all links (that I'm interested in) are processed.

**Here is my code:**

```
private void get_pages_2()
{
    // _repository.get_all_pages() gives me all the pages scraped so far (only from homepage)
    foreach (Page p in _repository.get_all_pages())
    {
        try
        {
            do_subpage(p.get_original_url());
        }
        catch (System.Net.WebException)
        {
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _frm.update_log("[!] Error creating subpage for: " + p.get_original_archive_url());
            _frm.update_log("[!] Error: " + e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
private void do_subpage(string link)
{
    List<Page_link> pages = new List<Page_link>();
    try
    {
        pages = get_pages(link);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (pages.Count == 0)
        return;

    // do_subpage(...);
    // should call again do_subpage(some_link), but got stuck here

}
```

The function do_subpage takes as parameter a link, and using the get_pages function, I get all the links I'm interested in, now I should call do_subpage on all links somehow ... but don't know how.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Can't you do a `foreach` on those `pages` and visit each link? Watch out for "back to previous page" links, that will throw you into an infinite loop! (maybe keep a list of "pages already visited")

Comment: @HansKesting  I can't really do the foreach on pages because, it will scrape the links of all the new pages, but it won't go even further, it will stop after 3 iterations, and I need it to work until everything is processed. The repository object keeps track of my visited pages.

Comment: What is the definition of `Page_Link`?

Comment: Page_Link is an object that contains some info about a page before it's actually processed.

Comment: Does it include all the links in the page?

Comment: You need a webrowser (HTMLClient) for each level of recursion to somplify the code.  If you don't then you will need to create an array of URL's on each page before you navigate to any of the links.  Then enumerate through the array recursively.

Comment: I've build the entire software already, but it's just scraping the homepage links, I want to do the same for each link scraped from the homepage and so on. Using a webbrowser would make me change the entire software, when it's almost done, but thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I could recommend you an idea of a simple web crawler from [this post](http://scraping.pro/simple-email-crawler-python/).